# Logical Replication does not Fire FOR EACH STATEMENT Trigger only FOR EACH ROW

Tags: postgresql, triggers, logical-replication

I'm using logical replication and managed to have the trigger fire when I have the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_updated_time_trig
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON test
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION set_updated_time();

alter table test enable always trigger set_updated_time_trig;
```

I tried with `ALWAYS` -> `REPLICA` too.

But when I use `for each STATEMENT`, it is no longer working.  I prefer to use `for each statement` since I can add also `OR TRUNCATE`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_updated_time_trig
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON test
    FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION set_updated_time();
```

How can I have a trigger that is fired on Truncate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can never work, because it is rows that are replicated, not statements. If you run an `UPDATE` that changes ten rows, the standby will modify those ten individual rows.  Contrariwise, if the `UPDATE` changes no row, nothing will be replicated. So it wouldn't make sense to execute statement level triggers on the standby, because they wouldn't work differently from row level triggers.

Comment: Very good explanation. Was not aware of this, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! If it is not supported, shouldn't it raise an exception upon trigger creation?

Comment: An exception would be too much, but a warning might be a good idea. You could write a patch or suggest it on the pgsql-hackers mailing list.

Comment: A clarification I got from pgsql-hackers group.  The trigger is fired only during the initial table synchronization since it is implemented like a COPY command and thus fires both row and statement triggers for INSERT.